# Rearranging array indexes

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array, indexing

I have a multidimensional array as follows

```
  Array
    (
        [0] => attributewidget Object
            (
                [_child] => Array
                    (
                    )

                [_parent] => 
                [_oid] => a_1
                [_errorMsg] => 
                [_debugTraceFunc] => 
                [classname] => AttributeWidget
                [version] => 1.0.0.0
                [attributeName] => 
                [comparableProperties] => Array
                    (
                        [0] => abbreviation
                        [1] => attributeName
                        [2] => classname
                        [3] => conditionRef
                    )

            )

        [1] => Array
            (
                [0] => attributewidget Object
                    (
                        [_child] => Array
                            (
                            )

                        [_parent] => 
                        [_oid] => a_2
                        [_errorMsg] => 
                        [_debugTraceFunc] => 
                        [classname] => AttributeWidget
                        [version] => 1.0.0.0
                        [attributeName] => 
                        [comparableProperties] => Array
                            (
                                [0] => abbreviation
                                [1] => attributeName
                                [2] => classname
                                [3] => conditionRef
                            )

                    )

            )
        [2] => Array
        (
            [0] => attributewidget Object
                (
                    [_child] => Array
                        (
                        )

                    [_parent] => 
                    [_oid] => a_3
                    [_errorMsg] => 
                    [_debugTraceFunc] => 
                    [classname] => AttributeWidget
                    [version] => 1.0.0.0
                    [attributeName] => cp1
                    [comparableProperties] => Array
                        (
                            [0] => abbreviation
                            [1] => attributeName
                            [2] => classname
                            [3] => conditionRef
                        )

                )

        )
    )
```

I ideally want to remove [1] => Array [2] => Array and rearrange the indexes.
  Is there a way where I can have the indexes rearranged as follows.

```
 Array
    (
        [0] => attributewidget Object
            (
                [_child] => Array
                    (
                    )

                [_parent] => 
                [_oid] => a_1
                [_errorMsg] => 
                [_debugTraceFunc] => 
                [classname] => AttributeWidget
                [version] => 1.0.0.0
                [attributeName] => 
                [comparableProperties] => Array
                    (
                        [0] => abbreviation
                        [1] => attributeName
                        [2] => classname
                        [3] => conditionRef
                    )

            )

                [1] => attributewidget Object
                    (
                        [_child] => Array
                            (
                            )

                        [_parent] => 
                        [_oid] => a_2
                        [_errorMsg] => 
                        [_debugTraceFunc] => 
                        [classname] => AttributeWidget
                        [version] => 1.0.0.0
                        [attributeName] => Name?
                        [comparableProperties] => Array
                            (
                                [0] => abbreviation
                                [1] => attributeName
                                [2] => classname
                                [3] => conditionRef
                            )

                    )



            [2] => attributewidget Object
                (
                    [_child] => Array
                        (
                        )

                    [_parent] => 
                    [_oid] => a_3
                    [_errorMsg] => 
                    [_debugTraceFunc] => 
                    [classname] => AttributeWidget
                    [version] => 1.0.0.0
                    [attributeName] => cp1
                    [comparableProperties] => Array
                        (
                            [0] => abbreviation
                            [1] => attributeName
                            [2] => classname
                            [3] => conditionRef
                        )

                )


    )
```

Comment: How did this array get created so inconsistently? Why does `[0]` point directly to an object, but `[1]` and `[2]` have an extra array in them? Maybe you should fix the code that creates the array in the first place so it doesn't do that.

Comment: Pro posting tip: [avoid requesting urgency of volunteers](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/326569).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Loop through the array, and replace any element that's a nested array with its first element, to remove that extra level of indirection.

```
foreach ($array as &$element) {
    if (is_array($element) {
        $element = $element[0];
    }
}
```